# differnce between sum(x,y) vs sum.call(undefined,x,y)

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning javascript from the definitive guide and many code examples use `xyx.call(undefined,/*args*/)` instead of just calling the function as `xyz(/*args*/)`.
I know that if the executing context is set to undefined then the value of this will refer to the global object . I'am not able to figure out why this is done in most examples as they don't depends on values from the global object. Can anybody help me understand the difference.

Some implementation of Array.protype.reduce

```
  if (!Array.prototype.reduce) {
      Array.prototype.reduce = function(callbackfn, initialValue) {
        "use strict";
        var O = Object(this),
        lenValue = O.length,
        len = lenValue >>> 0,
        k,
        accumulator,
        kPresent,
        Pk,
        kValue;

    if (typeof callbackfn !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    if (len === 0 && initialValue === undefined) {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    k = 0;

    if (initialValue !== undefined) {
        accumulator = initialValue;
    } else {
        kPresent = false;
        while(!kPresent && k < len) {
            Pk = k.toString();
            kPresent = O.hasOwnProperty(Pk);
            if (kPresent) {
                accumulator = O[Pk];
            }
            k += 1;
        }
        if (!kPresent) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }
    }
    while(k < len) {
        Pk = k.toString();
        kPresent = O.hasOwnProperty(Pk);
        if (kPresent) {
            kValue = O[Pk];
            accumulator = callbackfn.call(undefined, accumulator, kValue, k, O);
        }
        k += 1;
    }
    return accumulator;
};
```

}

and some use :

```
    if (!Array.prototype.reduce) {
     Array.prototype.reduce = function(callback /*, initialValue*/) {
     'use strict';
       if (this == null) {
  throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.reduce called on null or undefined');
}
if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
  throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
}
var t = Object(this), len = t.length >>> 0, k = 0, value;
if (arguments.length == 2) {
  value = arguments[1];
} else {
  while (k < len && ! k in t) {
    k++; 
  }
  if (k >= len) {
    throw new TypeError('Reduce of empty array with no initial value');
  }
  value = t[k++];
}
for (; k < len; k++) {
  if (k in t) {
    value = callback(value, t[k], k, t);
  }
}
return value;
```

};
}

so in one method the callback function is called using call() and in other implementation its not

Comment: `call` might do a little bit more than just control the this-context. Can you show us how this function is used?

Comment: In strict mode, `this` will be `undefined` and not `window`, in both `xyx()` and `xyx.call()`.

Comment: @Oriol so why use both interchangeably

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is functional OO language.It have different pattern to invoke a function. `xyz(/*args*/)` and `xyx.call(undefined,/*args*/)` are two different kind of invocations.

`xyz(/*args*/)` - In this case `this` have `window` as its value.

`xyx.call(undefined,/*args*/)` - In this case `this` will be nothing but context whatever we pass in call like in this case `undefined`.

Only special thing of using `xyx.call(undefined,/*args*/)` is that you have reliability of choosing your `context` in your function call.When you are writing object oriented JavaScript at that time value of `context` matters a lot. That's why it is more explicit to use `xyx.call(undefined,/*args*/)` over `xyz(/*args*/)`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your examples are using call for Array functions has to do with JavaScript's multiple (somewhat needless) array types.

As well as the standard object type that returns true on `arr instanceof Array`, there are also `NodeList`s returned from a `document.querySelectorAll` function, and other similar types. The important thing is, **these other types don't have all of Array's helper functions (*reduce, map, forEach*)**.

However, they still have all that they technically need for those functions to work; and the `.call` method helps you to do that. So, let's say I have two collections.

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('.baby');

arr.map(function(val) { return val + 1; }); // Okay!
nodelist.map(function(val) { return val.innerHTML; }); // doesn't work
```

I can pull off the .map call on the nodelist with `call`, by giving it a different target-object.

```
Array.prototype.map.call(nodelist, function...etc)

// Technically, this works too; just grabbing the method from our arr
// instance, but it's cleaner to refer to the original
// type's method.
arr.map.call(nodelist, function...etc)
```

To explain the code samples you posted; those are "polyfills" - browsers should have a "reduce" function themselves, but older browsers might not. So, we create it ourselves to replicate the same functionality.

Comment: That's true. But it doesn't explain `xyx.call(undefined)`.

Comment: @Oriol Hm. Actually, I can't explain that either; I thought that you were merely posing it as an example, but didn't notice that you explicitly said they call it with undefined. Honestly, even if technically there is a miniscule use to it...I would just avoid things like that however you can; it's going to kill code readability.